# Jenkins multiple jump host in publish over ssh

Tags: ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

If I configure multiple jump hosts(in jenkins) belonging to different subnets the ssh connection fails.
subnet a - 192.168.10.xxx
subnet b - 192.168.7.xxx

case 1: working
with jump host : 192.168.10.120

192.168.10.37 --> 192.168.10.120 --> 10.124.13.128

case 2: not working
with jump hosts : 192.168.10.120, 192.168.7.20

192.168.7.196 --> 192.168.7.20 --> 10.124.13.128

```
SSH: Caught exception [Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [backup]. 
Message [Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]]] 
Sleeping for [0]ms before trying again
```

*jenkins version : 2.401.3
publish over SSH : 1.25*

Comment: This is not a problem with Jenkins, but most likely with your network connectivity. Can you try to manually connect with ssh from each host to the next? If you can do that, so can Jenkins, and if you can't, Jenkins can't do it either.

Comment: Okay, I can check that. But how does jenkins decide which jump host to choose.

Comment: That is part of job configuration.

Comment: what if I've 2 jump hosts on different subnets, which is my actual questions.
in jenkins global config I've added jump hosts : ip1, ip2

Answer (score 0):

I am able to configure one jump host for each subnet to resolve this situation. Added a groovy logic to parameterize the correct jump host based on the node name in the publisherconfig(jump_host_subnet1 | jump_host_subnet2). It works now.

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: publisherConfig
```

[image]